# как посчитать участников определенного мероприятия в txt?

Tags: php, html, txt

Заданием было написать код php/html, где админ может сохранять через html-форму мероприятия, а именно название, место проведения и время, а также форму, где участники смогли бы зарегистрироваться (выбрать нужное меропритие, ввести свои имя и возраст). Все это должно сохраняться в два отдельных текстовых документа. Это есть и это работает, сложность возникла с последним заданием, а именно необходимо вывести на экран админа список всех сохраненных мероприятий и количество зарегестрированных участников для каждого. Возникает вопрос, как посчитать участников определенного мероприятия в этом текстовом документе и как вывести все существующие мероприятия из второго текстового документа? Возможно, есть специальные коды, но три прочесывала инет на эту тему и не нашла того, что нужно.

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Eventregistrierung</title>
        </head>
        
        <body>
        <h1>Eventregistrierung</h1>
        <h2>Wenn Sie Admin sind: </h2>
        <form action="index2.php" method="get">
    
        <p>Login:<br>
        <input type="Text" name="login"></p>
    
        <p>Passwort:<br>
        <input type="Text" name="passwort"></p>
    
        <p>Name:<br>
        <input type="Text" name="name"></p>
    
        <p>Ort:<br>
        <input type="Text" name="ort"></p>
    
        <p>Zeit:<br>
        <input type="Text" name="zeit"></p>
    
        <input type="Submit" name="" value="speichern">
    
        </form>
    
        <h2>Wenn Sie Teilnehmer sind: </h2>
            
            <form method="POST" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
                <label for="Vorname">Vorname: </label>
                <input type="text" id="vorname" name="vorname">
                <br>
                <label for="Nachname">Nachname: </label>
                <input type="text" id="nachname" name="nachname">
                <br>
                <label for="Alter">Alter: </label>
                <input type="number" name="alter" id="alter">
                <br>
                <?php
        $events = file("events.txt");
        echo '<select name=' . 'Event>';
        foreach($events as $event){
        $ph = explode("|", $event);
        $eventname = $ph[0];
        echo '<option value=' . "$eventname" . ' name=' . "Event" . '>'. $eventname . '</option>';
        }
        echo '</select>';
        ?>
    
                <input type="submit" id="registrieren" value="Registrieren">
            </form>
        </body>
    
    
    </html>
    <?php
    
    $reg = "events_u_reg.txt";
    if (isset($_POST['registrieren']) . !empty($_POST['vorname']) . !empty($_POST['nachname']) . !empty($_POST['alter'])) {
        echo "Sie wurden erfolgreich registriert!<br><br>";
        $heute = date("d.m.Y  H:i \\U\\h\\r");
        if($datei = fopen("events_u_reg","a")) {
            $text = $_POST['vorname'] . " " . $_POST['nachname'] . " | " . $_POST['alter'] . "J | " . $heute;
            fwrite($datei, $eventname . " | " . $text . "\r\n");
            $inhalt = file_get_contents("events_u_reg.txt");
        }
    
    } else {
        echo "Vor- und/oder Nachname nicht eingegeben";
    }
    
    ?>
```

и вторая часть

```
    <?php
    
    $login = $_GET["login"];
    $passwort = $_GET["passwort"];
    
    if ($login == "ADMIN" && $passwort == "admin")
    {
        if ( $_GET['login'] <> "" )
        {
         $handle = fopen ( "events.txt", "a" );
         fwrite ( $handle, $_GET['name'] );
         fwrite ( $handle, "|" );
         fwrite ( $handle, $_GET['zeit'] );
         fwrite ( $handle, "|" );
         fwrite ( $handle, $_GET['ort'] );
         fwrite ( $handle, "\n");
         fclose ( $handle );
         echo "Event wurde gespeichert.";
         exit;
         }
        }
    else
    {
        echo "Event wurde NICHT gespeichert. Überprüfen Sie Ihre Eingabe.";
    }
    ?>
```

[image: первый скрин]
[image: второй скрин]
[image: третий скрин]
[image: четвертый скрин]

Comment: Вы предлагаете нам набивать ваш код с изображения?

Comment: @ArchDemon: зачем что-то набивать? Вам просто предоставили возможность полюбоваться приятной ночной темой редактора. Пусть пальцы и глаза отдохнут :)

Comment: @ArchDemon: я не думала, что понадобится набивать его. добавила скорее с ознакомительное целью, чтобы было нагляднее. но сейчас добавлю код к вопросу

Comment: `passwort` - сразу вижу немца)

Comment: @OliverPatterson учусь в Австрии, так что коды все тоже на немецком)

Comment: Это довольно необычно увидеть было) А насчет темы.. Не проще хранить данные в JSON формате?

Comment: @OliverPatterson может и удобнее, да нельзя. мы не проходили их еще, а значит не можем использовать. код в общем очень дубово написан, потому что это школьный проект) и  мне банально не хватает знаний по теме, как это можно сделать лучше, да и учитель одобрил так. поэтому сейчас просто пытаюсь доделать последний пункт, а то сдача завтра утром

Comment: @UModeL , Блин, а тема-то действительно классная! Глаза радуются. Аж себе похожую поставил (Material Ocean). Релакс для глаз =)

Comment: Ну так в чем проблема? Это задание на-подумать, как прочитать данные из файла и составить по ним отчёт, и вы вряд ли выглядите в Интернете что-то по нему. Обычные операции по счету данных в массиве ...

Comment: @DanielProtopopov операция для Вас может и обычная, но я, например, не совсем понимаю, что необходимо сделать. Вы имеете ввиду определенную функцию с array?